# IO Monad - stop and return default(T) when condition not satisfied in Linq?

Tags: c#, linq, monads

The `sum()` in the following code will already get the sum of the `a`, `b`, `c` and 10 even if `a < b` (it will print the "We screwed up!" to indicate the expression failed the condition though). I tried to change the `Where<T>(...)` extension method to

```
public static IO<T> Where<T>(this IO<T> t, Func<T, bool> foo)
{
    return () => (foo(t()) ? t : Combine(() => default(T), () => { Console.WriteLine("We screwed up!"); }))();
}
```

But it will get a NullReferenceException exception on `select a + b + c + x`? Why? *There is no null value created?*

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var A = new Monad.IO<int>(() => { Console.WriteLine("A"); return 6; });
        var B = new Monad.IO<int>(() => { Console.WriteLine("B"); return 7; });
        var C = new Monad.IO<int>(() => { Console.WriteLine("C"); return 10; });

        var sum =
            from a in A
            from b in B
            from c in C
            let x = 10
            where a > b // Should fail the whole expression and return default(T) because a < b
            select a + b + c + x;
        Console.WriteLine(sum());
    }
}

static class Monad
{
    public delegate T IO<out T>();

    public static IO<R> SelectMany<S, C, R>(this IO<S> A, Func<S, IO<C>> foo, Func<S, C, R> bar)
    {
        var a = A();
        var B = foo(a);
        var b = B();
        var c = bar(a, b);
        return () => c;
        // return () => bar(a, foo(a)());
    }

    public static IO<T> Combine<T>(IO<T> a, Action b)
    {
        return new Func<IO<T>, IO<T>>(x => { b(); return x; })(a);
    }

    public static IO<T> Where<T>(this IO<T> t, Func<T, bool> foo)
    {
        return () => (foo(t()) ? t : Combine(t, () => { Console.WriteLine("We screwed up!"); }))();
    }

    public static IO<R> Select<S, R>(this IO<S> s, Func<S, R> foo)
    {
        return () => new Func<IO<S>, R>(x => foo(x()))(s);
    }
}
```

The code is from https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/alazarev/2017/05/20/fun-with-pure-c-and-monads/

Answer (score 1):

In the query, `foot(t())` is false, so you are taking the second half of the ternary, so you are returning (after `Combine` runs) `default(T)` where `T` is an anonymous type, so you are returning `null`.

Note that `from a in A from b in B` is translated into a call to `SelectMany` that creates a new anonymous type `new { a, b }` which is then passed to another `SelectMany` to handle the `from c in C` which results in another anonymous type `new { new { a, b }, c }`. Then the `let` causes a call to `Select` which returns another anonymous type `new { new { a, b }, c}, x }` which is what is passed into `Where` and the `default(T)` where `T` is an anonymous type is `null`.

Comment: But `T` is int?

Comment: Not after you go through `SelectMany`.

Comment: I added printing `typeof(T)` at the `Where` method and it got `<>f__AnonymousType2`2[<>f__AnonymousType1`2[<>f__AnonymousType0`2[System.Int32,System.Int32],System.Int32],System.Int32]`

Comment: Exactly - that is the type of `new { new { new { a, b }, c }, x }`.

Comment: So the type parameter `T` can be different type depends at different locations. It's sort of anti-intuitive.

Comment: I wouldn't say anti-intuitive. If you have a `List<int>` and a `List<string>` in your program, you aren't surprised that the constructor says `List<T>` and the `T` is different for each instance.

Comment: I meant in this question, the `T` has been assigned `int` at the beginning.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146703/discussion-between-netmage-and-dc7a9163d9).